# Scraping tables isn't always easy

Tags: html, r, parsing

I just edited my question to make it more general:
"How to scrape a table using r, when the format is not covered in any r functions?"

First of all, how should I know if the format matches what r functions like `rvest` can extract?

Second, let's say I tried all available scraping functions and they failed, how should I proceed? Write a parsing function myself? Is there an easier way to do it?

If `readHTMLTable` can not work for this instance, what are other options I should pursue besides parsing the html code in a huge string manipulation?

Comment: Reading the FM: The help example reads the document first: `doc = htmlParse(url);
 tableNodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//table");
 tb = readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[2]])`

Comment: Furthermore that doesn't look like an HTML table. Might look look a table but actually have a different structure.

Comment: Try reading with XML oriented functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the general answer to this is "scraping in any language is often a pain in the neck". This is because people put stuff on the web in random, crappy formats that are difficult for machines to parse.

I don't do an enormous amount of scraping, and don't have a better answer than "poke around in the source view of the page, use trial and error".

It looks like the table is badly structured; if you try to extract the `<tr>` (table row) you get junk ...

```
Weblink <- "http://hmofs.northwestern.edu/hc/crystals.php"
library(rvest)
rr <- read_html(Weblink)
tab2 <- html_nodes(rr,"table")[4]        ## get 4th table
vals <- html_text(html_nodes(tab2,"td")) ## get *all* elements in 4th table
```

Now take only the numeric values - the 7th column of the table is download information, and gets discarded this way

```
vals <- suppressWarnings(na.omit(as.numeric(vals)))
matrix(vals,byrow=TRUE,ncol=6)
```